# While loop in stored procedure loops only twice instead of 8 times

Tags: mysql, sql

**Table checkval**

```
val
----
5705
5704
5703
5702
5701
```

**Stored Procedure**

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE x INT;
DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
    DECLARE myType INT;
    DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR select val from checkval;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

    SET x = 10;

    WHILE x  >= 2 DO
##############

    OPEN cur1;

    read_loop: LOOP
        IF done THEN
            LEAVE read_loop;
        END IF;

        FETCH cur1 INTO myType;
        insert into myType values (myType);


    END LOOP read_loop;                              
CLOSE cur1;
        SET  x = x-1; 

    ##################
    END WHILE;

END
```

**Current Output**

```
5705
5704
5703
5702
5701--Loops only twice
5705
5704
5703
5702
5701
```

**Desired Output**

```
5705 - Loops 8 times
5704
5703
5702
5701
5705
5704
5703
5702
5701
5705
5704
5703
5702
5701
5705
5704
5703
5702
5701
5705
5704
5703
5702
5701
5705
5704
5703
5702
5701
5705
5704
5703
5702
5701
5705
5704
5703
5702
5701
```

Why is it even when I specify a while loop starting at `10` and ending at `2`, do I get my output only looped twice in the target table. I was hoping to see it repeated 8 times. Can yo pls help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DELIMITER $$

USE `test`$$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `fred`$$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`windows7.home` PROCEDURE `fred`()
BEGIN
    DECLARE X INT;
DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
    DECLARE myType INT;
    DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT val FROM checkval;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;
    SET X = 10;
    WHILE X  >= 2 DO
##############
    OPEN cur1;
    FETCH cur1 INTO myType;
    read_loop: LOOP
        IF done THEN
            LEAVE read_loop;
        END IF;
        INSERT INTO myType VALUES (myType);
        FETCH cur1 INTO myType;
    END LOOP read_loop;                              
CLOSE cur1;
        SET  X = X-1;
        SET done=FALSE;
    ##################
    END WHILE;
    END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: This too does it only once :( I can see you've added `DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;`

Comment: OK. I added what `N WEST` suggested and now it works fine. What you say?

Comment: what i say is i cant figure out how to re-use a cursor once it is close. also i would say i avoid cursors like the plague because they perform like dog doo doo and typically it suggests a few things that i wont go in to

Comment: try to use cursors as a last resort. there is probably ALWAYS a 100x faster way to do what you want

Comment: the problem with cursors is the following: they don't scale. there are times when a tricky scenario arrives that it seems like that is all you can use. but the more you use them, the more you think that is the way all work should be done (a common trap for new sql programmers). once you start nesting cursors the performance becomes exponentially painful

Answer (score 0):

I think it has to do with your handler. Try adding 
`SET done = FALSE`
After you close your cursor.

== EDIT ==

In general, you should avoid cursors like the plague.

You can do this with a ["Numbers" Table](http://dataeducation.com/you-require-a-numbers-table/)

```
create table Numbers (Number int);
insert into Numbers (Number) values (1);
insert into Numbers (Number) values (2);
insert into Numbers (Number) values (3);
insert into Numbers (Number) values (4);
insert into Numbers (Number) values (5);
insert into Numbers (Number) values (6);
insert into Numbers (Number) values (7);
insert into Numbers (Number) values (8);

select val from checkval cross join Numbers
where Numbers.Number between 1 and 8;
```

See this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/16ffb/1).

You can add values to the Numbers table to arbitrarily duplicate data as much as you need.

Comment: That worked, but in a funny way. Now I get everything 18 times:) Is there anything else I should remove or move?

Comment: @jmenezes see my edit for a way to do this without cursors at all.